# Wordpress query one post

Tags: wordpress

I want to retrieve the last post of the "actuality" post type, here is my query

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'actuality',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'order' => 'desc'
);
```

But I'm not sure of the correct way to print the result.

Here is what I've tried so far :

I used wp query but it seems I have to do a loop, as I only have one post I don't want to do a loop.

I tried to use *get_posts* method but the result looks like :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[3256]
      public 'ID' => int 25
      public 'post_name' => string 'post name' (length=1)
```

And so I have to do *$query[0]->post_name;* to get the result, which I think is the best solution I found so far but I wonder if there is a better way

I tried the *get_post*, but it ignores  *'post_type' => 'actuality',* and just retrive me the last post

Thank in advance !

Comment: get_post() requires the post_id as param, that's why it ignores your $args. Either use foreach loop instead of $query[0], or whire an SQL query with $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ....")

Comment: You can use `new WP_Query( $args )` just fine with what you're trying to do, just don't include the pagination. Avoiding the loop is unnecessary. Are you concerned with performance? That won't make a difference, as your query is only returning one post anyway.